# Calculate total working hour of employee in sql with only 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

Data in table `rider_status` will be like:

```
rider_id       online_status    date_time
   2               1            2019-10-17 08:00:40
   3               1            2019-10-17 09:30:30
   2               0            2019-10-17 12:30:40
   2               1            2019-10-17 14:50:50
   2               0            2019-10-17 18:50:50
```

- Online status 0 = not working
- Online status 1 = working

Now I want to calculate rider '2' total working hour of that particular date (for example '2019-19-17'). And further I want to calculate total hour of that rider for particular date range (for example '2019-10-05' to '2019-10-30').

My answer for rider_id '2' should be like:

```
12:30:40 - 08:00:40 = 04:30:12
18:50:50 - 14:50:50 = 06:00:00
                      --------
Total working hour  = 10:30:12
```

Comment: A hyperlink to an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx6O7.png) of a question is going to get downvoted till the sun don't shine. Leave your question as text please.

Comment: Why have you tagged MySQL and SQL Server here? Which RDBMS are you *really* using? I have removed the conflicting tags, please retag only the **correct** one. What have you tried so far to solve this problem, and why didn't it work? What does the question you have at hand have to do with php and android? This only seems to be related to sql.

Comment: MySQL I am using..
I want to use answer in php for api. And that api will be used in android.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? do `select version();` and share here

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will always get an online status of 1,0,1,0 etc then you can use LEAD() and LAG() to match the log-off to the log-on. Be careful to ensure that you are using the user ID in the window expression

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-lead-and-lag-function/](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php)

This will also apply to MSSQL from 2008 onwards

you can then use TIMEDIFF() to get the difference between the two times

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php

In MSSQL you would use DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Time1,Time2)

Comment: *"This will also apply to MSSQL from 2008 onwards"* `LEAD`/`LAG` is only available in SQL Server 2012+, not 2008+. All the [analytic functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) were added in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Btw it's an MySQL question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `1`s and `0`s are interleaved for each person, you can use:

```
select rider_id,
       sum(timestamp_diff(second, datetime, next_datetime)) as time_in_seconds
from (select t.*, 
             lead(date_time) over (partition by rider_id order by date_time) as next_date_time
      from t
     ) t
where online_status = 1
group by rider_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      Select rider_id, 
         case when lead(
         online_status) over
         partition by rider_id order by
         riderid, date_time <> online_status
         then 
         lead(date_time)over (partition 
             by rider_id order by rider_id) 
                -
               lag(updatedtime) over (partition 
             by rider_id order by rider_id) 

          End

        From table
```